# Operator theory : Expression of resolvent set.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space.

If a linear operator $T:D(T)\subset X\to X$ is injective (i.e., $\ker T=\{0\}$), then the inverse operator $T^{-1}:Ran(T)\to D(T)$ is defined.

Let $T:D(T)\subset X\to X$ be a linear closed operator.
The resolvent set of $T$ is $$\rho(T)=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid \ker (T-zI)=\{0\}, (T-zI)^{-1}\ \mathrm{is\ bounded\ }\}.$$

Then, I want to see $$\rho(T)=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid\ker (T-zI)=\{0\}, Ran(T-zI)=X \}.$$

$\supset$ follows by closed graph theorem. My book says $\subset$ is obvious but I cannot see why.

If $z\in\rho(T)$, then $T-zI:D(T)\to X$ is injective and $(T-zI)^{-1}:Ran(T-zI)\to D(T)$ is bounded. Then, why $Ran(T-zI)=X$ holds ? We have $Ran(T-zI)\subset X$ since the codomain of $T$ is $X$, but why $Ran(T-zI)\supset X$ ?

Comment: I think the definition of the resolvent set is not complete in your question. Indeed, you omit a condition about the $\text{Ran}(T-zI)$ should be dense in $X$

Comment: OK. As you say, $\overline{Ran(T-zI)}=X$ is necessary.
Even if we suppose $T$ is densely defined, is it insufficient for $\overline{Ran(T-zI)}=X$ ? @Youem

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=T-zI$.  If $\operatorname{Ker}(S)=\{0\}$, $S$ is closed and $S^{-1}$ is bounded then $\operatorname{Range}(S)$ is closed.

Proof: Let $z\in\overline{\operatorname{Range}(S)}$.  There's a sequence $\{z_n\}\subseteq \operatorname{Range}(S)$ such that $z_n \to z$.  The sequence $\{z_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.  Let $y_n = S^{-1}(z_n)$.  Since $S^{-1}$ is bounded, the sequence $\{y_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.  Let $y=\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n$.  Then $z_n = S(y_n)\to z$.  Since $S$ by assumption is closed it follows that $y\in \mathcal{D}(S)$ and $S(y) = z$.  So $z\in \operatorname{Range}(S)$.

Comment: Then, why does $Range(T-zI)=\overline{Range(T-zI)}$ imply $Range(T-zI)=X$ ?

Comment: It doesn't.  You have to assume $\operatorname{Range}(T-zI)$ is dense in $X$ like Youem said in a comment to your question.  It is easy to show an example why this has to be assumed.  For example, take $S$ to be the right-shift operator on $\ell^2(\Bbb{N}, \Bbb{C})$.  It has zero kernel, is closed, the inverse (the left shift) is bounded, but the range is orthogonal to the basis vector $e_0$ so isn't dense.